# Como contar la cantidad de veces que los valores de una lista coinciden con los valores de un diccionario

Tags: python, count

Me gustaría saber la cantidad de veces que hay algún valor de una lista (supongo que con `any()`) en un diccionario anidado

```
diccionario = {
    "Peliculas": [
        {
            "Titulo": "A",
            "Generos": ["Sigilo", "Rol"]
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "B",
            "Generos": ["FPS", "Terror"],
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "C",
            "Generos": ["FPS", "Terror"],
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "D",
            "Generos": ["Sigilo", "Rol"],
        }
    ]
}

elegido = input("¿Qué película elegirás? ")

generos = []
for item in diccionario["Peliculas"]:
    if item["Titulo"] == elegido:
        generos.append(item["Generos"])
```

Lo que hago aquí es tomar los 2 géneros del juego que el usuario elija y, buscar cuantas veces se repite en cada juego esos 2 géneros, por ejemplo, si eligiese A, se repetiría 2 veces en A, y 2 veces en D, por otro lado, 0 veces en B y C.

Acabo de aprender a usar `any()` y hace poco aprendí a usar el bucle `for`. Por lo que he investigado hasta ahora, las únicas 2 formas que encontré para contar ocurrencias son `Counter()` y `count()`, el problema es que ninguna funciona junto a `any()`

Lo más cerca que estuve de lograr lo que quiero es sin un any(), porque lo demas me daba error:

```
for item in diccionario["Peliculas"]
  print(generos.count(item["Generos"]))
```

Con esto logré que el sistema me diga en cuales películas se repiten los 2 géneros, pero yo quiero contarlos individualmente, quiero saber cuantas veces se repite 1 solo género.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usaremos un diccionario para contar cuantas veces aparece cada genero.

```
generos = {}  # Diccionario con el número de ocurrencias por genero
```

La llave será el género y el valor será la cantidad de veces que aparece.

A continuación pedimos el nombre de la película y la buscamos dentro del diccionario de películas para extraer los generos y poblar el diccionario `generos`.

```
elegido = input("¿Qué película elegirás? ")

#  Inicializa diccionario con los generos de la pelicula elegida
for item in diccionario["Peliculas"]:
    if item["Titulo"] == elegido:
        generos = {x: 0 for x in item["Generos"]}
        break
```

No necesitamos recorrer todo el diccionario de películas; podemos terminar tan pronto hayamos encontrado la película deseada.

Suponiendo que ingresamos la película "A", al terminar esta parte, tenemos el diccionario de géneros poblado así:

```
{'Sigilo': 0, 'Rol': 0}
```

Ahora hacemos una segunda pasada por las películas. De cada una sacamos la lista de géneros. Por cada género, vemos si está en el diccionario y en tal caso le sumamos 1 al contador

```
#  Recorrer las peliculas contando cuantas veces aparece cada genero.
for peli in diccionario["Peliculas"]:
    for gen in peli['Generos']:
        if gen in generos:
            generos[gen] += 1
```

Luego sólo queda imprimir:

```
#   Imprimir
for k, v in generos.items():
    print(k, v)
```

#### Demo

```
diccionario = {
    "Peliculas": [
        {
            "Titulo": "A",
            "Generos": ["Sigilo", "Rol"]
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "B",
            "Generos": ["FPS", "Terror"],
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "C",
            "Generos": ["FPS", "Terror"],
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "D",
            "Generos": ["Sigilo", "Rol"],
        }
    ]
}


generos = {}  # Diccionario con el número de ocurrencias por genero

elegido = input("¿Qué película elegirás? ")

#  Inicializa diccionario con los generos de la pelicula elegida
for item in diccionario["Peliculas"]:
    if item["Titulo"] == elegido:
        generos = {x: 0 for x in item["Generos"]}
        break

print(generos)
#  Recorrer las peliculas contando cuantas veces aparece cada genero.
for peli in diccionario["Peliculas"]:
    for gen in peli['Generos']:
        if gen in generos:
            generos[gen] += 1

#   Imprimir
for k, v in generos.items():
    print(k, v)
```

produce:

```
¿Qué película elegirás? A
Sigilo 2
Rol 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Está perfecto! Muchas gracias, aún que me molesta la idea de estar haciendo tantas preguntas, entiendo el procedimiento que hiciste, pero no logré pensarlo por mi mismo :( aún así gracias!

Comment: @Kalio. El aprendizaje es un proceso permanente.